# Aligning the contents of my footer properly

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-material

As I add more links to my footer the layout expands and the set of lists for each column becomes misaligned.

I want to ensure that each list set  for each column is align horizontally in the same row. e.g. The title for each column is in the same row

**levi**    |    **Using levi**    | **legal**

The below image has my column headers misaligned! :(. How would I align them properly so that when I add more to the list the alignment of the  content in each column remains constant.

[image]

This is an exmaple of how I want my footer to look.

[image]

[Here is my jsfiddle of how it is now](http://jsfiddle.net/b3m073hp/54/)

This is my HTML :

```
<md-layout id = "container" style = "max-height:40px;">

        <md-layout md-column  md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="33" md-flex-large="33" md-flex-xlarge="33">

                  <md-list>

                   <md-list-item  class = "md-display-2">levi</md-list-item>
                           <router-link :to = "{ name: 'About' }"><md-row>About</md-row></router-link>
                            <md-row >Customers</md-row >
                             <md-row >Contact Us</md-row >
                         <md-row >Support</md-row >
                         <md-row >Support</md-row >
                         <md-row >Support</md-row >
                      <md-row >Support</md-row >
                      <md-row >Support</md-row >
                      <md-row >Support</md-row > 
        <md-row >Support</md-row > 
              <md-row >Support</md-row >   
              <md-row >Support</md-row >   
              <md-row >Support</md-row >   
              <md-row >Support</md-row >   
              <md-row >Support</md-row >   
              <md-row >Support</md-row >   
               </md-list>   




                  </md-layout>


<md-layout md-column  md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="33" md-flex-large="33" md-flex-xlarge="33">


              <md-row class = "md-display-2" >Using levi</md-row >
                    <md-row >Business</md-row >
                    <md-row > <router-link class = "" :to = "{ name: 'Product' }">
                        Features
                    </router-link> </md-row>
                        <md-row >Pricing</md-row >
                         <md-row >Pricing</md-row >

                  </md-layout>

                     <md-layout md-column md-gutter  md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="33" md-flex-large="33" md-flex-xlarge="33">

                    <md-column class = "md-display-2">legal</md-column>
                    <md-column></md-column>
                        <md-column></md-column>

</md-layout>
```

Comment: `justify-content: flex-start` will get them to align their first items.

Answer (score 0):

Using `flexbox` is the best solution to your question. You can simply use it. The example in [codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/yoeyWv) shows how can you make such a footer. In the example, I used `flexbox`, since it is the most promising display layout method. There are many rules supported by most modern browsers in flexbox. Make use of it and simply make whatever you want. All the best

HTML Code:-

```
<div class='container'>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-heading">One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-heading">One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-heading">One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.list {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.list-heading {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```